# Getting advanced data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I got a table named 'objects, events & events_types', and these tables got a structure (not the all structure of it, but the basic information which I need to display from the database) and some information like this:

**Objects:**
**structure:**
*`id(INT), title(TEXT)...`*
**data:**

- 1, House #1
- 2, House #2
- 3, House #3

**Events:**
**structure:**
*`id(INT), object_id(INT), event_type(INT)`*
**data:**

- 1, 1, 3
- 2, 1, 1
- 3, 2, 4
- 4, 2, 5
- 5, 2, 1
- 6, 1, 1
- 7, 2, 2
- 8, 1, 3

**Events_Types:**
**structure:** *`id(INT), name(VARCHAR)`*
**data:**

- 1, Alarm
- 2, Dis/Arm
- 3, Fire
- 4, Alarm button
- 5, Unknown

I have a page, which loads all data from `events` table, but I need the page displays me only those objects from `objects` table which has a data into `events` table. It won't load me id(3) object from `objects` table because there is no row into `events` table which has `object_id` 3.

**I need a html table with the following columns**:

- `objects.id`
- `objects.title`
- `events_types.name`
- count from `events` table where `object_id` of this table is the `id` of `objects` table and `event_type` from `events` table is got by `$_GET['event_type']` from URL which will be defined as variable

**Example of the table with information from database where `$_GET['event_type'] = 1` and this '1' from `events_types` table is `Alarm`:**

```
| 1 | House #1 | Alarm: 2 |
| 2 | House #2 | Alarm: 1 |
```

but the House #3 won't be displayed because there is no data for it in the `events` table.

For the information, in the real table I've got around 200 records in the `objects` table and around 500 records in the `events` table every month. It's like a statistic system for me.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're describing, this sounds like a pretty straightforward join:

```
SELECT
  objects.id,
  objects.title,
  events_types.name
FROM
  objects INNER JOIN events on events.object_id = objects.id
  INNER JOIN events_types on events_types.id = events.event_type;
```

This should give you one record for each event, which will be labeled with the name of that event type. Any objects that don't have events associated with them won't show up.

Answer (score 1):

See if this query gets you the data you want:

```
SELECT O.id AS object_id, O.title, T.name, COUNT(*) as event_count
FROM Objects O
    JOIN Events E ON O.id = E.object_id
    JOIN Events_Types T ON E.id = T.id
GROUP BY O.id, E.event_type
```

Comment: @Vigo, if you receive an answer that was useful alongside the accepted answer, consider upvoting it. It's entirely optional, but it is a good way of expressing appreciation.